# I want to plot multiple geom_line in ggplot2 in for loop, so i am able to plot lines but facing problem in coloration. anyone can suggest how to do

Tags: r, linux

I want to plot multiple geom_lines in ggplot2 in a for loop. I am able to plot lines but am facing problem in coloring them. can anyone suggest how to do this?

```
pp=ggplot(a,aes(x=a$Nucleotide_position),y=data[,1:(length(a)-1)])
for (i in 1:(length(a)-1))
{ 
    pp=pp+geom_line(aes(x,y),data=data.frame(x=a$Nucleotide_position,y=a[,i]))
}

print(pp)
```

Comment: Insert in aes(x,y, color = factor(x)) or factor (y) it is not clear how ur data frame looks like.

Comment: It's hard to help right now without much information. [See here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example) on making a reproducible example. And why is this tagged Linux?

Answer (score 0):

Insert in aes(x,y, color = factor(x)) or factor (y) it is not clear how ur data frame looks like.